# How to input full width spacewhite in vim?

Tags: unicode, digraphs

In cjk characters set, full width space has the unicode value is U+3000, the english space unicode (half width space) value is U+0020.

How to input full width space in Vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The digraph for `U+3000` is `IS`, which you can enter with `CTRL-K IS`.  If you prefer to use a different digraph, you can assign one with:

```
dig ?? 12288
```

12288 is the decimal equivalent of 0x3000.  Or, you can make a map, e.g.,

```
inoremap <c-l> <c-k>IS
```

You can enter arbitrary unicode using `CTRL-V u3000` (see `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`).